# Looping through all the elements of an uint8_t * in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
uint8_t *var;
var=//something;
```

Now I want to loop through each element of this var
how to do this 
please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make loop like in plain C. `uint8_t *var` is just an C array.

```objective-c
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; ++i) {
    var[i] = ...; // Do whatever you want
}
```

For example

```objective-c
uint8_t *v = (uint8_t *)malloc(5 * sizeof(uint8_t));

for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    v[i] = i;
}

for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    NSLog(@"%d\n", v[i]);
}

free(v);
```

Note that `uint8_t` is the same as `unsigned char`:

```objective-c
#ifndef _UINT8_T
#define _UINT8_T
typedef unsigned char         uint8_t;
#endif /*_UINT8_T */
```

Comment: And how to convert a NSString into uint8_t * ?

Comment: @user1825882 You could use `cStringUsingEncoding:` and `strcpy`: `uint8_t *str = (uint8_t *)malloc((nsstring_str.length + 1) * sizeof(uint8_t)); strcpy(str, [nsstring_str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);` But note that `uint8_t *` and `char *` aren't the same, first is unsigned when second is signed, so you'll receive a warning. Use `char *` instead.